# Creating 3 small tables side by side centered

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create 3 small tables side by side that are centered in the page. I have the following code so far but it doesn't work. I'm breaking my head trying to figure out how to do this and it seems like it would be simple, but its not, at least for me its not. Can someone please help me out with this? I have attached an image as well as to what I am trying to create.

```
<table align="center"><tr><td>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</td><td>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>test 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<td></td>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>test 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: The first table you're using is not really the best practice.You already got a good answer for your problem, but I believe you should use a div to act as the container for your other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by a typo, as pointed out. My idea would be to remove the parent table and use `display: inline-table` to line them up and then `text-align: center` on a container to center them.

Moving away from nested tables results in much more readable markup. Also, the `border` attribute should be removed and created in CSS instead.

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  display: inline-table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td { 
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have typo in your HTML. After the second child table you have

```
<td></td>
```

While you probably meant

```
</td><td>
```

So this:

```html
<table align="center"><tr><td>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</td><td>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>test 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td><td>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>test 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
<div class="container" align="center">
<table>
<tr>
<td>column 1</td>
<td>column 2</td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td>column 1</td>
<td>column 2</td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td>column 1</td>
<td>column 2</td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

css

```
.container
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
table
{
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline;

}
```