# Create 3 boxes side-by-side

Tags: html, css

This is what I have so far, thanks to MRManSam, who helped out on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806403/creating-3-small-tables-side-by-side-centered). How can I make the boxes look like they do in the image?

[image]

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  display: inline-table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td { 
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```
<div class="wrap">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Care to show the HTML and CSS you've written to accomplish this? And why is your image so big?

Comment: How's this different from your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806403/creating-3-small-tables-side-by-side-centered)? BTW, learn how to crop an image.

Comment: I tried to use <th> but that messed up the whole layout with that

Comment: Okay, you've added HTML. Are you asking how to style the boxes now?

Comment: well, i guess, because i want to make them look like that, unless there is a different way to do it without css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a million ways to do this, but here is just one:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <header>
         <h2>stuff</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="body">things</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <header>
         <h2>stuff</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="body">things</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <header>
         <h2>stuff</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="body">things</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    /* body hack for jsfiddle, do not use */
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width:900px;
}
div.box {
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #555;
    min-width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.box > header {
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 1px 20px;
}
div.box > header > h2 {
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align: center;
}
div.box div.body {
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#333;
    background:#eaeaea;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Please see the result here:
http://jsfiddle.net/u5jxk2qs/

[image]

It does just what you wanted.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Not to mention divs are just a better way to go for this in general.

Comment: yeah what is this 1995?  xD  Lets make this with frames and tables!!